# Scrapy not showing Project-only commands ( crawl check list edit parse bench) in windows may i know reason?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

Scrapy not showing Project-only commands ( crawl check list edit parse bench) in windows may i know reason ?

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>scrapy -h
Scrapy 1.1.3 - no active project

Usage:
  scrapy <command> [options] [args]

Available commands:
  bench         Run quick benchmark test
  commands
  fetch         Fetch a URL using the Scrapy downloader
  genspider     Generate new spider using pre-defined templates
  runspider     Run a self-contained spider (without creating a project)
  settings      Get settings values
  shell         Interactive scraping console
  startproject  Create new project
  version       Print Scrapy version
  view          Open URL in browser, as seen by Scrapy

  [ more ]      More commands available when run from project directory

Use "scrapy <command> -h" to see more info about a command
```

Answer (score 2):

> [ more ] More commands available when run from project directory

This means that you need to navigate to your project directory in your terminal. You can use command `cd` (stands for change directory) to do that.

```
$ cd C:\projects\myproject
$ scrapy --help
```